# Pandas does not set column width (In Jupiter Notebook /Lab)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, width

I want to show each row of pandas DataFrame in One line, and as I searched, it seems the solution is to set the display column width as None. However, it does not do the job for me.

Here is a test code to show the problem.
I need to have each row in a single line (so basically I expect it to increase the columns width to a point where 'It issssssssssssssssss justttttttttttttttttttttt a tesssssssssssst' is shown in one line and not multiple lines).

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
A=pd.DataFrame(['It issssssssssssssssss justttttttttttttttttttttt a tesssssssssssst', 'It is just a test'] )
df=pd.concat([A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A], axis=1)
df
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (the only one?) is to change the CSS [*white-space*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to `"nonwrap"` with [`set_properties`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties.html?highlight=set_properties#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_properties) :

```
(
    df
        .set_axis(range(len(df.columns)), axis=1)
        .style.set_properties(
            **{"white-space": "nowrap"}
        )
)
```

Output :

[image]

***Update :***

With jupyter notebook, you can make a `custom.css` and put it in the [*default-config-dir*](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html#configuration-files) :

```
.dataframe td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The tree should look like this (*in Windows*) :

```
C:
┗━━ Users
    ┗━━ Timeless
        ┗━━ .jupyter
            ┣━━ custom         # <-- make a new folder
                ┗━━ custom.css # <-- put there the css
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, but needs to be done each time you want to display a dataframe. I hoped there would be something available in the display settings that could be set once

Comment: I made an update to the answer. Can you check it out ?

Comment: I copied your css file in the config path, and it actually worked! Thanks :)

Comment: Hey Timeless, it seems your custom.css does not work in the new Jupyter 7. Any fix?